# How do I add specific entries in columns to a final total?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, finance

To start, I'm trying to create a spreadsheet to help keep track of my spending and earnings throughout the year in an effort to crack down on my budgeting and excessive spending. I would like to figure out how to add a specific spending or earnings based on whether I used cash or card. I have no idea how to do this and where to start or if I'm even asking in the right place(sorry if I am) but any help would be greatly appreciated. This is a link to a rough design of my spreadsheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H1wLZaxPEq60i8lFcjBtSWsTfZ4SOkT2Vt2JygiSnt8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=SUMIF(E2:E, "Cash", C2:C)
```

[image]